# how can I create a new variable with the same data type of a specific variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to create a new variable in the same data type of my variable `Message`. How can I do that?

I tried the following code. but I got an error.

```
MessageDTO Message;
var Message2 = new Message.GetType();
```

Error:

> Message is a variable but is used like a type.

Here is my code:

```
public string Send(MessageDTO message)
{
     MessageDTO Message2 = new MessageDTO();
     if (message is Email)
     {
         Message2= new Email();
     }else if(message is SMS)
     {
         Message2= new SMS();
     }
    // rest of code ...
 }
```

Where

```
 public class MessageDTO
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public MessageType Type { get; set; }
        public string? Subject { get; set; }
        public string? TextBody { get; set; }
        public string? HTMLBody { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset SendDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime SendTime { get; set; }
 }

public class Email : MessageDTO
{
   public string From{ get; set; }
   public string To{ get; set; }
}



 public class SMS : MessageDTO
 {
   public string SenderLine{ get; set; }
   public string[] To{ get; set; }
 }
```

I want to make my code open for extension, but closed for modification (i.e. If I add other types of messages, the `Send` method remains unchanged.). The `Send` method becomes shorter like this:

```
public string Send(MessageDTO message)
{
     MessageDTO Message2 = new Activator.CreateInstance(Message.GetType());
     // rest of code ...
 }
```

Comment: can you give a bigger picture, i.e. why you want to?

Comment: Technically, you can put it as this: `var Message2 = Activator.CreateInstance(Message.GetType());`

Comment: What scenario would this be useful in?

Comment: Most likely an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: you can create overloads for the `Send` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not clear to me why you need to make a new object in `Send()`. Knowing that, maybe another solution would be better. But I'll just go with the assumption that it is necessary.

One approach is to have `MessageDTO` be responsible for creating a new object of the correct type:

```
public class MessageDTO
{
    public abstract MessageDTO CreateAnother();
}

public class Email : MessageDTO
{
   public override MessageDTO CreateAnother() => new Email();
}

...

public string Send(MessageDTO message)
{
   MessageDTO Message2 = message.CreateAnother();
}
```

The `CreateAnother()` function could also do something more sophisticated, depending on what you need. For instance it could clone the existing object, not just create a default new one. (In that case I'd probably name it differently!)